# Passing parameters and event to a handler function

Tags: jquery, events, parameters

I have the following code which seems to work.

```
box.bind('mousedown' , function(event){
    box.css('background-color' , '#ff00ff');
    box.bind('mousemove' , movehandler);
});

function movehandler(event){
    box.css('background-color' , '#ffff00');
    // do things to move div            
}
```

But when I try the following and pass parameters to the `movehandler` function things don't seen to want to work.

```
box.bind('mousedown' , function(event){
    box.css('background-color' , '#ff00ff');        
    startY = event.pageY;
    boxtop = box.position().top;
    box.bind('mousemove' , boxhandler(startY, boxtop));
}); 

function boxhandler(a, b) {
    box.css('background-color' , '#ffff00');
    dist = (event.pageY - a);
    var val = b + dist;
    box.css('WebkitTransform' , 'translate(0px, '+ val +'px)');
}
```

So is it possible to pass arguments/parameters into a handler function and retain the info associated with the actual event?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that as you have `box.bind('mousemove'` inside `box.bind('mousedown'`, then binding of mousemove will be done each time mousedown happens.

You can try something like:

```
var startY = null;
var boxtop = null;
// Start moving
box.bind('mousedown' , function(event) {
  box.css('background-color' , '#ff00ff');        
  startY = event.pageY;
  boxtop = box.position().top;
});

// Finish moving
box.bind('mouseup', function() {
  startY = null;
  boxtop = null;
});

// Handle moving
box.bind('mousemove' , boxhandler);


function boxhandler(event) {
  if (startY !== null) {
    box.css('background-color' , '#ffff00');
    dist = (event.pageY - startY);
    var val = boxtop + dist;
    box.css('WebkitTransform' , 'translate(0px, '+ val +'px)');
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply and for the re-worked script.  I did know that I had the box.bind('mousemove') inside the box.bind('mousedown') but it was the only way I could get it to work but I like your way.